# structural equation modelling - Lavaan

Tags: r, model, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I am running a structural equation model and I always obtain something similar to this result, where one of the observed variables that are part of the latent variable **have an estimate of 1 and no other information**. Is this how it is suppose to be? Does the model assume that the first variable (y1) entered is the defining one and tests whether the other ones contribute to the model?

**Model output**

```
 Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
         X =~                                                           
         Y1         1.000                               0.681    0.710
         Y2         0.900    0.437    2.060    0.039    0.612    0.619
```

Comment: This is a constraint that is added to allow the model to be identified (i.e. so that there are fewer parameters needed to be estimated). If i remember correctly,there are other ways to constrain the model.

Comment: Is this not a good way of doing it? What do you suggest? I am fairly new to SEM. Thank you!

Comment: You may find this small article helpful: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/when-does-selection-of-indicator-variable-constraints-matter-in-cfa-and-sem/

Comment: Thank you, that is really useful! So I was assuming it was doing something closer to what they described.